# ALTER DATABASE command to set log filegrowth and size?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to alter the LOG file through script when creating a database?
I need to set the file size, growth etc, but NOT specify where the DB is to be created.
e.g.

```
CREATE DATABASE [NewDatabase]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [NewDatabase] 
    MODIFY FILE
    (SIZE = 10MB,
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
    FILEGROWTH = 1MB);
GO
**ALTER DATABASE [NewDatabase]
    MODIFY LOG
    (MAXSIZE = 200MB, 
    FILEGROWTH = 1MB 
    );
GO**
```

Comment: unlimited size with 1MB growth increments? Make sure [you keep the number of VLFs in check](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/transaction-log-vlfs-too-many-or-too-few/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already wrote it, you just need to specify logical file name of the log file.

```
ALTER DATABASE [NewDatabase]
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = 'NewDatabase_log',
SIZE = 200MB,
FILEGROWTH = 1MB)
```